# How to modify this command for selector `a`?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract links from the following element

`<a class="link-right verbtable" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer">Full verb table</a>`

with below code

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
r = session.get(url, headers = headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

output = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.link-right.verbtable [href]')]
print(output)
```

and the result is `[]`. I think `output` is empty because there is something wrong with `[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.link-right.verbtable [href]')]`. In particular, `'.link-right.verbtable [href]'` maybe not correct because `link-right.verbtable` is not of `div`.

Could you please help me correct this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer'
r = session.get(url, headers = headers) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

output = [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.link-right.verbtable')]
print(output)
```

prints:

```
['https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/conjugation/aimer']
```

You can also have the output line like this:

```
output = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('.link-right.verbtable')]
```

I prefer to have get but both works perfectly..

Comment: Can we modify your code to restrict to the subset `<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling"`?

Comment: Oh `output = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling .link-right.verbtable')]` works ^^

Comment: Yes it does @LAD

Comment: The command `[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling .link-right.verbtable')]` returns all values, but I only need the first one. I tried `[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling .link-right.verbtable')]` but it does not work. Do you have any idea to achieve my goal?

Comment: ```[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling .link-right.verbtable')[:1]]``` @LAD

Comment: But your command still find all the values. My desired command is to stop after getting the first one. This would improve the performance in case the procedure is repeated thousands of times.

Comment: No no.. Try again: ```[tag.attrs['href'] for tag in soup.select('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling .link-right.verbtable')[:1]]```

Comment: It's my bad. I'm sorry for my rush ^_^

Comment: I would like to thank you and other users again. Without your dedicated help, I would never do it.

Comment: @LAD you can vote up comments to if it is helpful comments.